# Discord bot stuck in "Signalling " state when trying to establish a voice connection. discordjs v13

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, voice

So I've been working on a discord music bot, but whenever I try to get the bot to join a voice channel, nothing happes and I have no errors. I used `console.log(getVoiceConnections())` to try and find what was wrong, and it says `status: "signalling"`. I think it's is stuck in signalling, but I have no idea how to fix it. These are all my intents:

```js
({ intents: [
             Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
             Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
             Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, 
             Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES
            ] });
```

and this is the code I'm using to join:

```js
    const {
            joinVoiceChannel,
            createAudioPlayer,
            createAudioResource,
            getVoiceConnections
           } = require('@discordjs/voice')
    
    module.exports = {
        name: 'join',
        description: "attempts to join a voicechannel",
        execute(message, args) {
            const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
                channelId: message.member.voice.channel.id,
                guildId: 828953538952298517,
                adapterCreator: message.channel.guild.voiceAdapterCreator,
            });
    
    
            let audioPlayer = createAudioPlayer();
            connection.subscribe(audioPlayer);
    
            console.log(getVoiceConnections())
            const resource = createAudioResource('')
            audioPlayer.play(resource)
    
    
            message.reply('Joining!');
        }
    }
```

Here's the [official documentation](https://discordjs.github.io/voice/modules.html) if anyone can find my solution in there

Comment: did you try adding `async-await`?

Comment: you mean like `async execute`

Comment: then `let audioPlayer = await...` and `const resource = await...`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `guildId` field in your `joinVoiceChannel()` should not be an `integer`, but a `String`. Due to you having it as an `integer` it probably doesn't know what guild to connect to and is just signaling for the channel to find.